# wrong interpolation in scipy.interpolate.interp1d

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have problem with scipy.interpolate.interp1d

```
df = 
ang frc
-40 -15605.47
-30 -16051.253
-20 -10895.4
-10 -6205.733
0   -1730.65
10  2697.85
20  7217.59
30  12022.48
40  17298.647
```

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

df = pd.read_csv('111.txt', sep='\t')
print(df)
interpi = interp1d(df['frc'], df['ang'], fill_value='extrapolate')
print(interpi(-17000))
```

It gives import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

df = pd.read_csv('111.txt', sep='\t')
print(df)
interpi = interp1d(df['frc'], df['ang'], fill_value='extrapolate')
print(interpi(-17000))

```
It gives -8.717 which is clearly wrong!
I rather it gives Error

can anyone help?
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on your definition of "wrong".
To view this problem from the perspective of the interpolator (or rather extrapolator):
If `x_new = - 17000`, i.e., outside of the range, the following points (blue in the picture below) are used to extrapolate: `(-15605.47, -40)` and `(-16051.253, -30)`. From those, the interpolator learns that a **decrease in `frc` leads to an increase in `ang`**. See the following picture. I clipped interpolation range for visibility.[image: Interpolation]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I'm still puzzled.

Comment: A. Why doesn't the interpolator checks himself. B. How can I fix it?